# Getting properties programmatically from Log4j2 XML config

Tags: java, log4j2

In my Log4j2 config file, I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" strict="true" name="XMLConfig" packages="org.apache.logging.log4j.test">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="baseDir">log-dir/</Property>
        <Property name="defaultLogfileName">default-log-file</Property>
    </Properties>
```

Now, in some of my code, I create custom loggers. I need to access the value of "baseDir" and change it. I've tried using `getProperties` from the context like this:

```
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
Configuration configuration = context.getConfiguration();
configuration.getProperties();
```

But the map that comes back has the keys "hostname" and "contextName". Not the properties map that I was looking for.

I thought that I might be able to get it from the rootLogger:

```
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
Configuration configuration = context.getConfiguration()
for (Property p : configuration.getRootLogger().getPropertyList())
{
    ...
}
```

But this yields a NullPointerException because getPropertyList returns null.

So, how can I access the property with the name "baseDir" so that I can programmatically create a new logger, but with a different base directory?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46581587/log4j2-xml-define-jdbc-appender-and-pass-property-from-xml-configuration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The class *Configuration*, which is returned by *context.getConfiguration()* is not a kind of *PropertyConfiguration* class. It cannot be used for access of log4j2.xml values, since it is the very different *Configuration* class, tailored for logging settings.

It is possible to extract *baseDir* definition into separate properties file. This provides the common source for both programmatic and non-programmatic log4j configuration: programmatically it can be accessed as a regular property configuration file; log4j2 configuration can access it as a properties lookup.

This looks something like this:

1. The external property file logsCommons.properties is located in the same folder with log4j2.xml and has the property:

   ```
   baseDir=log-dir
   ```
2. The log4j2xml is defined as following:

   ```
   <Properties>
       <Property name="baseDir">${bundle:logsCommons:baseDir}/</Property>
       <Property name="defaultLogfileName">default-log-file</Property>
   </Properties>
   ```

---

*From the OP:*

In addition to moving the value of baseDir to a properties file and references it as `${bundle:logsCommon:baseDir}` as described above, I did this to get to my actual solution:

get the StrSubstitutor:

```
String baseDirVar = configuration.getStrSubstitutor().getVariableResolver().look‌​up("baseDir");
```

Then I needed to do a replacement:

```
String baseDir = configuration.getStrSubstitutor().replace(baseDirVar);
```

Now I can reliably get (and modify when necessary) the base directory for logging that now comes from the properties file.

Comment: Does this mean that my code would need to access `baseDir` by loading the properties file? Or can I access it through the log4j2 API?

Comment: I figured it out! First, I needed to get the StrSubstitutor: `String baseDirVar = configuration.getStrSubstitutor().getVariableResolver().lookup("baseDir");` Then I needed to do a replacement: `String baseDir = configuration.getStrSubstitutor().replace(baseDirVar);` Now I can reliably get (and modify when necessary) the base directory for logging that now comes from the properties file.