# Log4j2 XML define JDBC Appender and pass property from xml configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j2

i have a maven project runnable with SpringBoot.
I defined a JDBC appender and would like to pass jdbc properties from log4j2.xml

Reading [Getting properties programmatically from Log4j2 XML config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44142592/getting-properties-programmatically-from-log4j2-xml-config) i did:

1. PUT log4j2.xml and logsCommons.properties in src/main/resources folder
2. In log4j2.xml

   ```
   <Configuration status="warn" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
      <Property name="baseDir">${bundle:logsCommons:baseDir}/</Property>
      </Properties>
      <Appenders>
        <JDBC name="jdbcAppender" tableName="event_log">
          <ConnectionFactory class="Log4j2CustomConnectionFactory"
           method="getDatabaseConnection"/> 
          <Column name="dt_event" isEventTimestamp="true" />
          ....
        </JDBC>              
      </Appenders>
      <Loggers>
      </Loggers>
   </Configuration>
   ```
3. Use below java code:

   ```
   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.SQLException;
   import javax.sql.DataSource;
   import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.ConnectionFactory;
   import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverManagerConnectionFactory;
   import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection;
   import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory;
   import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource;
   import org.apache.commons.pool2.ObjectPool;
   import org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool;
   import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
   import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
   import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;


   public class Log4j2CustomConnectionFactory{

   private static interface Singleton {
       final Log4j2CustomConnectionFactoryINSTANCE = new Log4j2CustomConnectionFactory();
   }

   private DataSource dataSource;

   private Log4j2CustomConnectionFactory() {

       LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
       Configuration configuration = context.getConfiguration();

       String baseDirVar = configuration.getStrSubstitutor().getVariableResolver().lookup("baseDir");

       /* HERE baseDirVar IS NULL */
       /* also configuration.getStrSubstitutor().getVariableResolver().lookup("java"); return NULL */



   }

   public static Connection getDatabaseConnection() throws SQLException {
       return Singleton.INSTANCE.dataSource.getConnection();
   }

   /*..initializing Datasource with properties retrieved from Log4j2.xml.*/

   }
   ```
4. In debug, instruction         `configuration.getStrSubstitutor().getVariableResolver()`
   returns
   [Debug Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GvNU.png)

Can you please help me to understand what's wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Which version of `log4j2` you are using ? In similar case, with `log4j2 version 2.8.2` , I got `${bundle:logsCommons:baseDir}/` in `baseDirVar`  variable.